# Is there a scripting command that can execute a specific php method from a php file using a bash script

Tags: php, bash, shell, command-line, command-line-interface

I believe the title speaks for itself but I will elaborate a little more. I have a php file called hello-world.php. I also have a bash script called testBash.sh.

Inside of **hello-world.php** I have two methods **helloWorld()** and **helloName($name)**

Basically what I want to do is from within my bash script (**testBash.sh**) ... I want to pass in the parameter and execute the **helloName($name)** method. The parameter will be given from within the bash script.

Here is what I have so far.

**testBash.sh**

```
INPUT="Bobby"

// THIS IS WHERE I AM HAVING TROUBLE
TEST= php -r "require 'hello-world.php'; helloName("$INPUT");"

echo "$TEST"
```

**hello-world.php**

```
function helloWorld() {

    return "Hello, World!";

}

function helloName($name) {

    return "Hello, $name!";

}
```

In a perfect world when I echo "$TEST" the results of that function should be displayed.

Ex: Hello, Bobby!

Is this possible? I have looked online for solutions but this is the closest I have come to find one. Any input or advice would be great. Thanks!

Comment: How about `TEST=$(php -r "require 'hello-world.php'; echo helloName(\"$INPUT\");")`? Not on a linux computer atm so can't test.

Comment: Wow, this was exactly what I was looking for. Works perfectly! Would it be possible to elaborate just a bit on this?

Comment: Sure, I'll add this as an answer with a little explanation then, give me a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
TEST=$(php -r "require 'hello-world.php'; echo helloName(\"$INPUT\");")
```

I guess this should work as well (single quotes for function param):

```
TEST=$(php -r "require 'hello-world.php'; echo helloName('$INPUT');")
```

Basically,

- adding `echo` in PHP ensures the php command sends the result of `helloName` to the output,
- `$(command)` tells the bash command to return its output as a value,
- that value is finally assigned to `TEST`.